# Another way to set mnemonic for JMenuItem?

Tags: java, mnemonics

So, I have a "Open Project" menu item, and I want to set mnemonic to it. I prefer it to be 'e' character from Project word. But when I set it with

```
openProjectMenuItem.setMnemonic('e');
```

it sets 'e' character from Open word as mnemonic. Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3):

The method `setMnemonic(char mnemonic)` is obsolete, you should use `setMnemonic(int mnemonic)` with the appropriate `VK_E` instead.

In any case the default behaviour is to underline first occurrence of the letter, if present. If you want to customize this thing you should look at `AbstractButton` class, it has a method (doc [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setDisplayedMnemonicIndex%28int%29):

```
public void setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(int index)
```

that does exactly what you need. So:

```
openProjectMenuItem.setMnemonic(VK_E);
openProjectMenuItem.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(9);
```